# Delete from MySql table using aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, sql-delete

I'm wondering if it's possible to delete columns using *some* aggregate functions (found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

For example say I wanted to delete the last `user` from my database, it'd be easy if I could just run:

```
delete from user where id = MAX(id);
```

But running this will give me the following error:

> ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Is this possible with ***mysql*** or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a query like this:

```
delete from user where id = (select id 
                             from (select MAX(id) as id 
                                   from user) as t)
```

Comment: Perfect...Should've used my brain to find this out instead of asking SO :')

Answer (score 0):

Try with another select as follows:

```
delete from user where id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user);
```

Answer (score 0):

As another option, is to use temporary variable:

```
set @id = (select max(id) from user);
delete from user where id = @id;
```

Comment: This one seems to throw an error, `ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:

```
delete from user where id = (select max(id) from user);
```

Comment: Note that this answer has already been posted, thanks though.